# AWS Cognito Integration

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, singleton, amazon-cognito

I am working to integrate the Login Screen of an application I am working to create with AWS Cognito and have been following the step by step instructions to connect with the server.

STEP 5 OF 7
Copy the Mobile Hub Helper and Custom Code

Copy the src/main/java/com/amazonaws folder from the code you downloaded into the java/com folder of your Android Studio project.

This folder contains a set of helper classes that have been custom generated for you. These were generated based on your project configuration and on the AWS cloud resources and identifiers that were created for you when you configured the project. These classes simplify the use of all the SDKs that are required to support your project.

It also contains the source code for the AWSMobileClient which is a singleton component which bootstraps the app and creates an identity manager to establish the user identity with Amazon Cognito. If your project uses the Mobile Hub NoSQL feature the AmazonAws folder will also contain model classes that simplify your access to the DynamoDB tables you configured.

I believe I am running into problems with the last half of this bit as I am unsure what a singleton component is or how to insert it into the code. I have created it as a Java class and included the included code

package com.your.app;

import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.mobile.AWSMobileClient;

/**
 * Application class responsible for initializing singletons and other common components.
 */
public class Application extends MultiDexApplication {

```
private final static String LOG_TAG = Application.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Application.onCreate - Initializing application...");
    super.onCreate();
    initializeApplication();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Application.onCreate - Application initialized OK");
}

private void initializeApplication() {

    // Initialize the AWS Mobile Client
    AWSMobileClient.initializeMobileClientIfNecessary(getApplicationContext());

    // ... Put any application-specific initialization logic here ...
}
```

}

however I get a red line in the manifest because it is not connected to an XML file, however the instructions never say to add an XML or to attach it to an XML file so im not sure how to connect these features. I imagine that the Application class should be populated following startup i.e. App opens to the login screen and it somehow initiates the communication with the server to transmit the strings which are typed into the text fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.jason.mvp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Dreamer"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Application"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.jason.mvp.LoginActivity" >


    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

can anyone help me!? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Jessy,

It looks like you didn't do step 7 yet or did it wrong? Rather than have .application as an activity you should instead add it directly under application:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Dreamer"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="com.example.jason.mvp.Application">
```

Have you started the integration steps for "User Sign-In" yet?  You have to walk through those steps as well.  One way to display the login view is to use a splash activity as is discussed in step 3 of the user sign-in integration steps.

Kevin